# jssor: $Pause() not pause the slider

Tags: jssor

**Jssor Initialization:**

```
        function imageAndVideoJssor()
        {
            jssor_slider_image_and_video = '';
            var slides = $('#jssor_all_play_show_slides>div');
            var slideCount = slides.length;
            var thumbNailNavigatorChanceToShow = slideCount < 2 ? 0 : 2;
            var _CaptionTransitions = [];
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] = {$Duration: 600, $Clip: 8, $Move: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutExpo};

            var displayPieces = 4;
            var arrowNavigatorSteps = 3;
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
                displayPieces = 2;
                arrowNavigatorSteps = 1;
            }

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: false,
                $FillMode: 2,
                $Loop: 0,
                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                    $ChanceToShow: thumbNailNavigatorChanceToShow,
                    $DisplayPieces: displayPieces,
                    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                        $AutoCenter: 2, //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                        $Steps: arrowNavigatorSteps                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    }
                },
                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                    $ChanceToShow: 0
                },
                $CaptionSliderOptions: {//[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$, //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions, //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 0, //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 0                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssorTagId = 'jssor_all_play_show';
            jssor_slider_image_and_video = new $JssorSlider$(jssorTagId, options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider_image_and_video.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 720));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);

            jssorResolutionAdjustor(jssorTagId);
            $(window).resize(function() {
                jssorResolutionAdjustor(jssorTagId);
            });
            //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //}
            //responsive code end
            setTimeout(function() {
                showAllImageVideoJssorJwPlayer();
            }
            , 0);

            jssor_slider_image_and_video.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
                console.log('from index = ' + fromIndex + 'slide index = ' + slideIndex);
                    showAllImageVideoJssorJwPlayer();
            });
        }
```

The above code is used for initialize the jssor and in that function at the very last I called the function `showAllImageVideoJssorJwPlayer()` whose declaration is given below. I called this function on after initialized jssor and on event park of jssor.

**Video and image controlling code:**

```
    function showAllImageVideoJssorJwPlayer()
    {

        var slideCount = jssor_slider_image_and_video.$SlidesCount();
        console.log('slideCount = ' + slideCount);
        if (slideCount === 1)
        {
            var activeVideo = $('[id="jssor_all_play_show_slides"]:eq(1)>div:last-child img');
        } else {
            var activeVideo = $('.pav img:visible');
        }
        console.log('Video ' + activeVideo.data('video'));
        if (activeVideo.data('video') !== undefined)
        {
            console.log('inside video');
            jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Pause();
            var videoObj = {};
            videoObj.videoSrc = activeVideo.data('video');
            videoObj.thumbSrc = activeVideo.attr('src');

            jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance = jwplayer("jssor_all_video_screen").setup({
                file: videoObj.videoSrc,
                image: videoObj.thumbSrc,
                width: 720,
                height: 400
            });



            jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.onReady(function() {

                jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.play();

                jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.onPlay(function() {
                    $('body').on('click', function() {
                        jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.pause(true);
                        jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Pause();
                    });

                    jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Pause();
                });

                jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.onComplete(function() {
                    jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Next();
                    jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.remove();
                });
            });

        } else if (activeVideo.data('video') === undefined)
        {
            if (typeof jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance !== "undefined")
            {
                jssorAllImageVideoPlayerInstance.remove();
            }
            jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Play();
        }
    }
```

I like to pause the slide show once video was played for that I used `jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Pause();`. The code reached the `console.log('inside video');` so this represent clearly that on next line the slideshow should stop. But actually it not stopping the slide to prove that,

**Here attached firebug screen shot**

[image: firebug console log]

In console log The first occurrence of **inside video** is border in red on that time itself `jssor $pause` should work but it doesn't work don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The instance.$Pause call stops the slider from auto playing.
It would not freeze the slider suddenly.

Actually, if a slider is paused, it will stay at current slide until you click arrow or bullet button.

Comment: but it not stops the slider if you see that log after red bordered rectangle i console logged slider movement as 'from index = 4 slide index = 5'. It go on cyclically even called the method $pause of jssor object

Comment: It go on cyclically even called the method $pause of jssor object and that console log is written inside the $EVT_PARK function so on every slide moved the from and slide index logged which is results in slide is in autoplay because I didn't trigger any event for slider manually using either keyboard or mouse. On default duration finished the slider move to next div.

Comment: I can't see the image clearly. I checked again and again, it works ok. Please double check your code.

Comment: as you requested me to double check code if I remove `jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Play();` this line at the very last of function `showAllImageVideoJssorJwPlayer()` and i manually slided the slider working properly but if autoplay on by calling `$Play()` issue arises do you have any clue for this?

Comment: if possible will you please tell what are the things mainly i have to check if you tell that it will be great help for me to solve this issue. Because this is one of the prolonged issue in development server.

Comment: Let me check out your 2 questions tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know its a right solution but I solved it by putting the following snippet

```
    if(typeof jssor_slider_image_and_video === 'object')
    {
        jssor_slider_image_and_video.$Pause();
        delete jssor_slider_image_and_video;
    }
```

just above the instantiation in the function `imageAndVideoJssor()`

before the following code

```
    var jssorTagId = 'jssor_all_play_show';
    jssor_slider_image_and_video = new $JssorSlider$(jssorTagId, options);
```